# how to store facebook page id in mysql database?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to find a way to store the users facebook page id in mysql database using php.

currently i can get the page id from the URL in the iframe within the facebook page like so:

```
<?php
// PATH TO FB-PHP-SDK
require 'src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
  'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'cookie' => true,
));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if( $page = $signed_request['page'] ) {
    echo $page['id'];
}
?>
```

The code above echo's the page id correctly but it will only do that within the facebook iframe page tab.

I ask the users to allow my application to connect to their pages like so:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&scope=email,manage_pages,offline_access&redirect_uri=https://dev.socialtalkie.com
```

they need to open that URL in the browser.

so, i need to know how I can get the users page id once they allow the app to connect to their page and store it in mysql database?

is there anyway to open that URL within my own site so I can store the page id ? if so, how?

any advise would be appreciated.

Thanks